# How to get current date in time4j library?

Tags: java, time4j

how I can get current Persian Date with `time4J`in java?

```
PersianCalendar jalali = new PersianCalendar();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Javadoc of `PersianCalendar`](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/calendar/PersianCalendar.html):

```
PlainDate today = SystemClock.inLocalView().today();
PersianCalendar jalali = today.transform(PersianCalendar.class);
```

Comment: The short form for this code is just: `PersianCalendar.nowInSystemTime()`. This refers to the usage of system timezone and system clock, but my comment (of the other answer) also shows options how to choose another timezone or another clock.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are multiple ways to do so:

1. [`nowInSystemTime()`](http://www.time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/calendar/PersianCalendar.html#nowInSystemTime--)

   ```
   PersianCalendar jalali = PersianCalendar.nowInSystemTime();
   ```
2. using transformation

   ```
   PlainDate today = SystemClock.inLocalView().today();
   PersianCalendar jalali = today.transform(PersianCalendar.class);
   ```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes, multiple ways. The first option is mainly for convenience. Users can also choose the timezone or the clock. Examples which also show that an explicit transformation is not necessary: `SystemClock.inZonalView(ASIA.TEHRAN).now(PersianCalendar.axis());` or a web-based clock `HttpClock hc = new HttpClock("http://www.google.com/"); jalali = hc.inLocalView().now(PersianCalendar.axis());` An  SNTP-clock or a fixed test clock are also possible etc.